# Splunk lookup script lifecycle

Tags: python, lifecycle, splunk

I have written a python script that Splunk launches with a lookup command.

Like this: `source="*" | lookup my_script`

This script, as a first thing, creates a client object that uses later on for its internal logic. This client connects to a server and has a caching layer. This operation is time consuming and, in order to avoid repeating it, I store the client in python `globals()`.

I noticed that when I run the lookup passing the results of a splunk search to it, it gets called one time for each result found by the search. This would not be a big issue if the whole client wasn't recreated each time, because the `globals()` namespace is empty as the whole python process was invoked separately for each record and destroyed once the record is processed by the script.

- Does anyone know the details of lookup scripts lifecycle?
- Is each record passed to a separate python invocation?
- Is there a way to store the client object to make it survive each lookup script invocation?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is the same as yours - that the script is invoked once for each result.  Splunk executes a script by forking itself, which means nothing is preserved between invocations.

Consider saving global objects on disk or in the KVStore.  See https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/developapps/manageknowledge/kvstore/

Comment: Unfortunately, as I said in the initial post, the object I need to keep in memory between each record processing is a complex client which has http client features, a caching layer and more. I cannot just save it on disk, but even if I could the impact on performance would be huge. Ideally, I'd set it in some kind of Splunk global registry (if such thing exist) so that it survives subsequent script calls.

Comment: Consider again using the KVStore - it's an in-memory data store that survives script calls.

Comment: kvstore creates a collection that only accepts data that are serializabile into JSON, mine is not. If you look at the `insert` method of the kvstore collection, you'll find that it does ```return json.loads(self._post('', headers=KVStoreCollectionData.JSON_HEADER, body=data).body.read().decode('utf-8'))``` This won't work with my client object.